# How to code review "new" repository in github

Tags: github, pull-request, review

I want to review code that is totally new. But, I am unable to create a pull request, nor I am able to add a comment.

Does github supports reviewing code for only changes to existing repositories? What if it is a new repository built only on master? Can someone get code review through Github for a totally new repository and have others comment on it?

Comment: Your question doesn't help anyone. Yes, GitHub has an excellent code review mechanism. First, make sure you are comfortable with git and GitHub. If you want to create a pull-request go through this link https://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/ Also, take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5wpJ5VimSU

Comment: Do go through the GitHub Guides: https://guides.github.com/

Comment: @SaugatAcharya: Your answer doesn't help. I see there are two ways to create pull request - "Pull Request from a forked repository AND
Pull Request from a branch within a repository." But what if it is a new repository built only on master? Can someone get code review through Github for a totally new repository and have others comment on it?

Comment: If you only have master branch you still can review/comment on the files by explicitly clicking on a commit. For example: https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master - click on any commit message to see what's changed, now hover your cursor on the line numbers to add a comment. But, this method is only suitable for a single commit and that is not how we review. In most cases we will need to code review on a bunch of commits and that's when we require pull requests.

Comment: Consider this article for "How to do a full review of your repository contents on GitHub." 
 https://www.exasol.com/en/resource/how-to-do-a-full-review-of-your-repository-contents-on-github/